# Renaming file using batch over network

Tags: batch-file, variables, command, rename

I am working on creating a backup program using python and batch scripts.  The entire program will work if I don't have the program export a copy of the incremental backup to a shared network folder(I want to have redundancy so I have it save to server and two other terminals). I can manually go into cmd prompt and type out the ren cmd and it will do it without any issue. The problem arises when I attempt to use a variable with the ren cmd.

**Example of set /p**

```
REM Load text file with first variable
set loadDD002=C:\Backup\Bin\DD002.txt
SET /p back1Directory=<%LoadDD002%
REM Show the Defined Variable
echo back1Directory
```

**Example of contents of DD002.txt**

```
//SERVER/NetShare
```

**example of cleanup/renaming**

```
del "%back2Directory%\backup7.zip"
ren "%back2Directory%\backup6.zip" backup7.bak
ren "%back2Directory%\backup5.zip" backup6.zip
ren "%back2Directory%\backup4.zip" backup5.zip
ren "%back2Directory%\backup3.zip" backup4.zip
ren "%back2Directory%\backup1.zip" backup2.zip
ren "%back2Directory%\backup.zip" backup1.zip
```

**Error receiving**

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect
```

I apologize for any editing faux pas as I am very new to this site.

Thank you,

Comment: Apologies, I labelled the Cleanup/Renaming wrong. It should be "%back1Directory%\backup*.zip" backup*.zip

Comment: Use `Echo(%back1Directory%`, not `echo back1Directory`.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm.. I figured it out. See below:

```
set "network1=%back1Directory:* =%
```

Then

```
set "network1=%back1Directory:* =%
```

WOOO